# Issue with search form admin panel after PHP migration

Tags: php, wp-admin, admin-menu

I have website hosted on OVH, and currently I am using PHP v. 5.3. Since OVH will stop supporting it soon I have to migrate to 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 or 7.

I've tried 5.6 and 7 but what happens is that search option in admin panel (i.e. while searching user for users list) stopped working. I can see blank screen. When I revert to 5.3 everything works fine again.

In debug log I can see following issues, however, they are present in both cases, 5.3 as well as higher...

[14-Jun-2016 12:55:49 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WP_Import has a deprecated constructor in /home/nomadfloip/mdb_prd/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php on line 38

[14-Jun-2016 12:55:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/nomadfloip/mdb_prd/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php:38) in /home/nomadfloip/mdb_prd/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/wp-social-login.php on line 64

[14-Jun-2016 12:55:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/nomadfloip/mdb_prd/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php:38) in /home/nomadfloip/mdb_prd/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/wp-social-login.php on line 64

[14-Jun-2016 12:55:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  bbp_setup_current_user was called **incorrectly**. The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init(). Please see [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) for more information. (This message was added in version 2.3.) in /home/nomadfloip/mdb_prd/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3897

Any idea where to look for a reason?

Comment: sounds like it is time to upgrade everything and fix all the reported errors

Comment: What do you mean by fix reported erros? unfortunately they are related to 3rd party plugins so its quite challenging...